# How to validate user when password is hashed on the previous database

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-1.0, identityserver4

I have this web app that's been around for a year.

- Framework: ASPNET MVC
- ORM: Entity Framework 5
- Database: SQL Server
- Authorization: uses scaffolded `AccountController`

I want to migrate it to ASP.NET Core and refactor some of my code. My plan is to create a separated project responsible for authorization/authentication, for this I decided to use IdentityServer4. As for my ORM, I would like to use Dapper.

My problem is I don't know how to validate my user when logging in since passwords in the database were hashed.

Comment: I assume you don't have the original part of the code which hashes the user passwords?

Comment: @BoyPasmo can you use same code which used to hash password to create new password then update result you get with real value in database?

Comment: Hashing of Passwords was provided by the framework. I don't have the code for it. And I think the framework used one-way hashing so I can't see the real value of it.

Comment: Do you have the salts?  If not, or if it wasn't salted, simply have everyone with an old password change it.  Do a double verification, email their address on file, have them click a link from it with a UID that redirects them to a password page.  Enter the new password, done.

Comment: @Aaron I was thinking the same thing, but is it the right path?

Comment: Asp. NET keeps the password, salt, and I believe algorithm info in a single field. I'd guess you're able to use the PasswordHasher class in core, too.

Comment: Do you think you can point me to the page?

Comment: I would personally try to get everyone on the same path.  If you can't get the old ones imported for any reason, it's much better for maintenance to just have them change it... You can also ensure they use "One upper, one lower, special, etc" or whatever company policy is - it may have changed between the original and new systems.

Comment: You have a point, that will be my last option but for now I think I'll with @john idea. Thank you all